# How to I restore my old default keychain?

Tags: macos, password, keychain, login

I just re-initialised my login keychain because I had troubles after upgrading to Sierra (it kept asking me the login password). So I followed up an article in apple.com and recreate my keychain. Upon creation, the window said that the current default keychain would not be deleted, it would be moved elsewhere instead.

Now I have to restore it, but where was it moved? How can I find and restore it?

Thank you, regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I can answer by myself. Doing the above, keychain will in fact store a copy of the old 'defaults' (all the previous... Don't why they're called 'defaults'). The copy (at least in Sierra) is located in

```
~/Library/Keychains/login_renamed_1.keychain-db
```

You can have back all your data by opening Keychain and drag/drop that file on the left column, on the top area. Once done, you'll be able to find all your old data below (Password, keys, etc...)

The apps will find them again, eventually asking you the password (the login one) to open the backed-up ones.

Comment: Thank goodness. I thought I lost all of my passwords.